# Set HTTP requests defaults in IntelliJ HTTP request client editor

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ http request editor; is there a way to set the common config for all the requests in the file (and globally) ?

For example I would like to specify an authorization header for all the requests.

Current code

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/foo
Authorization: Bearer my-token
```

The code I am trying to achieve:

Desirable code

```
<common headers>
Authorization: Bearer my-token

GET http://localhost:8080/api/foo
GET http://localhost:8080/api/bar
GET http://localhost:8080/api/baz
```

Comment: not sure I follow you... You can use variables for common headers as described in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.1/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html#using_env_vars - is it a feature you are looking for?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, variables only solve the part of the problem - storing the token in the config. Still for every request I would manually need to add :`Authorization: Bearer {{token}}` so clicking the 'play' button near the Spring Controller methods wouldn't' work the first time.

Answer (score 18):

It's a bit late but i will try to give an answer in case someone is coming around.

I'm not sure it is exactly what you are looking for but maybe it help.

If you are getting your token dynamically from a login endpoint, you can store the token in a variable and use it later in any request.

Exemple:

```
### Login

POST http://localhost:8080/login
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "email": "someEmail",
  "password": "somePassword"
}

> {%
    client.global.set("auth_token", response.headers.valuesOf('x-auth-token')[0]);
  %}

### Get user

GET http://localhost:8080/user/someUserId
Authorization: Bearer {{auth_token}}
```

In this case, i store my token coming from the header `x-auth-token` in a variable `auth_token`. Than i use it in the authorization header for all my next requests.

Found from [the official JetBrains website HTTP response handling exemples](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/http-response-handling-examples.html#script-var-example)

Have a nice day!